# Database initializer does not work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to create a database with data already loaded.
It doesn't return any error, just not workinkg. The database is created perfectly but empty. I think that the problem is in the appConfig

Context:

```
namespace Domain.DAL
{
    public class LandingContext : DbContext
    {
        public LandingContext() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.ConString)
        {
        Database.SetInitializer<LandingContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<LandingContext>());
        Database.Initialize(true);
        }

    public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AbsProduct> Products { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Initializer:

```
namespace Domain.DAL
{
    public class LandingInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<LandingContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(LandingContext context)
        {
            Car kangoo = new Car(100, 2, "kangoo");
            context.Products.Add(kangoo);
            context.SaveChanges();

            base.Seed(context);
        }

    }
}
```

And the appconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Domain.Properties.Settings.ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ENZO-PC;Initial Catalog=GLB-Landing;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type=" DAL.LandingContext, Domain">
      <databaseInitializer type="DAL.LandingInitializer, Domain" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the method 'Seed'?

Comment: How should I call him and where? From the Context I have no way to access the Initializer

Comment: Any place you want.  Probably after you get the Products which is what you are putting into the database.

Comment: @jdweng But the 'Seed' method is protected, i can't access...

Comment: Why did you make it protected?

Answer (score 0):

I reeplace

```
    Database.SetInitializer<LandingContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<LandingContext>());
```

for:

```
    Database.SetInitializer<LandingContext>(new LandingInitializer());
```

And work...